# Existing template for coalescing random walk

Tags: random-process

I would like to simulate a 2-dimensional random walk on a lattice where the particles coalesce/merge when they occupy a similar site on the lattice. Would it be possible to tweak in an efficient way the function `RandomWalkProcess[p,q]` such that when two particles collide they merge into one?

**Edit**: Here is my attempt:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
tMax = 100;
gSize = 5;(*Grid Size*)
x = Table[0, {t, 1, tMax}]; 
n = 10; (*number of particles*)

pos0[n_] := 
 pos0[n] = RandomInteger[{-gSize, gSize}, {n, 2}];(*Initial positions*)

x[[1]] = DeleteDuplicates[pos0[n]];
For[t = 2, t < tMax + 1, t++,
 x[[t]] = 
  DeleteDuplicates[x[[t - 1]]]; (*if particle collides, merge it*)
 
 n = Length@x[[t]];(* update number of particles*)
 
 pt = RandomInteger[{1, n}];(*Choose random point*)
 
 x[[t]][[pt]] += (-1)^Table[Random[Integer], {2}];(*move it*)
 ]
```

And here is a plot:

```
Animate[ListPlot[x[[time]], 
  PlotRange -> {{-3*gSize, 3*gSize}, {-3*gSize, 3*gSize}}], {time, 1, 
  tMax, 1}]
```

Are there any simple way to represent the result in a similar way to this picture?
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you, please, share with us the code that you are having trouble with, so that we may better help you?

Comment: Hey Matt, try this perhaps?

    `iterator[list_] := (list /. l_List /; Length[l] == 3 :> l + RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, 3]) /. {a___, s1_List, b___, s2_List, c___} /; s1 === s2 :> {a, s1, b, {}, c}` as your function,
    `path = NestList[iterator, starts, 10000];` to generate paths,
    `paths = Transpose[path] /. {} -> Nothing;` to transpose as desired and terminate "joined" paths, and
    `Graphics3D[{RandomColor[], Line@#} & /@ paths]` to display?

Comment: i forgot to add that `starts` is, understandably, a list of starting points: `starts = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {20, 3}]` (for example)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice template following Ben Kalziqi's comments:

#### Template

```
n = 10; (*Number Particles*)
tMax := 1000
dim = 2;
iterator[list_] := (list /. 
    l_List /; Length[l] == dim :> 
     l + RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, dim]) /. {a___, s1_List, b___, 
     s2_List, c___} /; s1 === s2 :> {a, s1, b, {}, c}
starts = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {n, dim}];
path = NestList[iterator, starts, tMax];
paths = Transpose[path] /. {} -> Nothing;
```

#### Plotting:

**3D**

```
Graphics[{RandomColor[], Line@#} & /@ paths]
```

**2D**

```
ListPointPlot3D[paths, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "t"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, 
   FontFamily -> "Times"}(*,ScalingFunctions\[Rule]{None,None,"Log"}*),
  ImageSize -> 700]
```

**1D**

```
For[j = 1, j < n + 1, j++,
 For[i = 1, i < Length[paths[[j]]] + 1, i++,
  AppendTo[paths[[j]][[i]], i]]]
ListLinePlot[paths]
```

A nice bonus would be that if two particles collided then the colour of their trajectory becomes the same...
[image]