# Plot trajectories of 1D coalescing particles: Reshape irregular size array

Tags: list-manipulation

*My question boils down to:*
**How can I reshape a list composed of sublists of different sizes?**

---

I am trying to plot the trajectories of 5 particles (1D), and if they collide, they merge into one same particle.

After running the simulation, I end up with a data set composed of sublists, where each sublist corresponds to the position of each particles. For example:

```
data={{3, 5, 4, -5, -3}, {3, 5, 3, -5, -3}, {4, 5, -5, -3}, {4, 
  5, -5, -2}, {4, 5, -5, -3}, {5, 
  5, -5, -3}, {6, -5, -3}, {6, -6, -3}, {6, -6, -4}, {6, -7, -4}}
```

where `data[t]` represents the position of the five particles at time $t$. The main problem is that as time evolves, the size of `data[t]` is not the same. For example from `data[5]` onward there are only 3 particles remaining. So I cannot transpose my dataset to to a list plot.

In this particular situation I guess I would like to obtain the following:

```
newData={{3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6}, {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}, {4, 
  3}, {-5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -5, -3, -3}, {-3, -3, -3, -2, -3, -3, -3, \
-3, -4, -4}} 
plot = Rotate[ListLinePlot[newData], -90 Degree]
```

[image]

Non essential question: would it be possible two only have one colour for each tree?

Comment: Hi Matt—if `data[[t]]` represents the position of your particles at time `t`, how are you keeping track of which particle is which? _E.g._, in your original data, `Length@data[[1]]==5`, but `Length@data[[10]]==3`. Two particles disappear; are they guaranteed to be particles 4 and 5? Put another way: I don't understand how you could get the `{4,3}` part of your `newData` from `data`.... and I don't get where the `-7` goes, for example. This seems ill-posed.

Comment: Yes this is an other obstacle indeed... They are not per se particles 4 and 5. particles only move by $\pm 1$ steps, so I was thinking that one way to fix it would be to sort each sublist, extract all first elements into a new list, and repeat until all sublists are empty. But I have a hard time implementing it.

Comment: The particles trajectories are actually generated from the following code: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/249281/existing-template-for-coalescing-random-walk

Comment: Probably a bad habit to spread questions out like this, but given the problem statement there—I would perhaps write a function which adds one random step at a time to a list of starting points, and checks at each point for any equivalence between the points. If equivalence is found, iteration can stop on one of the lists. Then, you could `Nest` this function... it's a bit of a messy ask. You could also just pre-generate a bunch of walks, then look between them for matches, and delete anything that comes after the matches using replacement rules.

Comment: Thanks, I created a new post as it seemed to far away from my original question, but I understand your point. The problem with pre-generating the walks is that there are many generated random numbers that will not be used, and I would like to avoid this. Regarding your improvement method, I will try it, if I manage... Thanks!

Comment: What is the scale of the problem you're trying to do? I have a method that I _think_ works and takes ~2.3 seconds to do 10k steps (each) for 20 particles...